# Python click - allow a prompt to be empty

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm using the click library for a CLI application. I have various options that the user can specify, and most of them have prompts turned on. However, even if an option isn't required, if you set click to prompt for the option, it won't accept an empty response (like just hitting enter). For example:

```
@click.option('-n', '--name', required=True, prompt=True)
@click.option('-d', '--description', required=False, prompt=True)

>>> myscript -n Joe
>>> Description: [Enter pressed]
>>> Description: [Enter pressed; click doesn't accept an empty parameter]
```

Is there a way to get around this, or would this require a feature request?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

when you add `default=""` then an empty string is also accepted:

```
@click.option('-d', '--description', prompt=True, default="")
```

Note that `required` is not a possible argument for option, at least [according to the docs](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#click.Option)

Comment: Actually it is. The `Option` and `Argument` classes are both subclasses of the `Parameter` class. So that's not the issue.

Comment: the trick actually is the `default=""` which allows for an empty string. Did this work?

Comment: That did it. Sorry, I didn't even notice the `default` you were using earlier. Can you make a note of that in your response to make it obvious that's what is needed?

Comment: sure, I added a sentence at the top